# Why this Spring application with java-based configuration don't work properly

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I started recently a project with the Spring framework with the ojective to develop it without none XML config file, only Java code.

In this current moment, I add the follow files to my project:

**WebAppConfig.java**

```
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(value="org.webapp")
@Configuration
public class WebAppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/css/**").addResourceLocations("/css/").setCachePeriod(31556926);
        registry.addResourceHandler("/css/**").addResourceLocations("/fonts/").setCachePeriod(31556926);
        registry.addResourceHandler("/img/**").addResourceLocations("/image/").setCachePeriod(31556926);
        registry.addResourceHandler("/js/**").addResourceLocations("/js/").setCachePeriod(31556926);
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver getInternalResourceViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }

}
```

**SecurityConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("kleber").password("123").roles("USER");
    }

}
```

**SecurityWebApplicationInitializer.java**

```
@Order(value=2)
public class SecurityWebApplicationInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {

    public SecurityWebApplicationInitializer() {
        super(SecurityConfig.class);
    }
}
```

In this state, when I run the application (in Eclipse) the browser shows the default login form from Spring Security, and an error 404 after I submit this form. If I try enter directly the url localhost:8080/spring/index, I can access the page which should appears afeter the login form.

If I add this class:

**WebAppInitializer.java**

```
@Order(value=1)
public class WebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) {
      // Create the 'root' Spring application context
      AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
      rootContext.register(WebAppConfig.class);

      // Manage the lifecycle of the root application context
      container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));

      // Create the dispatcher servlet's Spring application context
      AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext dispatcherContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
      dispatcherContext.register(DispatcherConfig.class);

      // Register and map the dispatcher servlet
      ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = container.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(dispatcherContext));
      dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
      dispatcher.addMapping("/");
    }

}
```

In replacement to web.xml, following the instructions from official documentation, in this link:

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/WebApplicationInitializer.html

I can't even access the login page. Same thing happens if I add to the class SecurityConfig the method:

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/css/**", "/fonts/**", "/image/**", "/js/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("spring/index").permitAll()
                .failureUrl("spring/erro_login").permitAll()
                .defaultSuccessUrl("spring/home")
                .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutSuccessUrl("spring/logout")
                .permitAll();
    }
```

Someone can see what am I missing?

ps.:

My controler is this:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="spring")
public class SpringController {

    @RequestMapping(value="index")
    public ModelAndView index() {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
        mav.setViewName("index");
        return mav;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="home")
    public ModelAndView home() {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
        mav.setViewName("home");
        return mav;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="erro_login")
    public ModelAndView erro_login() {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
        mav.setViewName("erro_login");
        return mav;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="erro_nao_autorizado")
    public ModelAndView erro_nao_autorizado() {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
        mav.setViewName("erro_nao_autorizado");
        return mav;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="logout")
    public ModelAndView logout() {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
        mav.setViewName("index");
        return mav;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

This error is displayed in the console of Eclipse

```
Mar 29, 2014 1:28:02 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
Grave: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot initialize context because there is already a root application context present - check whether you have multiple ContextLoader* definitions in your web.xml!
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:265)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4937)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

After the answer given to this topic, I try remove one of two conflicting registration of ContextListeners, from SecurityWebApplicationInitializer or WebAppInitializer. In both cases, I get this error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public javax.servlet.Filter org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.springSecurityFilterChain() throws java.lang.Exception] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'spring/index?error' is not a valid redirect URL
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:581)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1025)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:921)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:487)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:628)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4937)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public javax.servlet.Filter org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.springSecurityFilterChain() throws java.lang.Exception] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'spring/index?error' is not a valid redirect URL
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:181)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:570)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'spring/index?error' is not a valid redirect URL
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(Assert.java:65)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler.setDefaultFailureUrl(SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler.java:98)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler.<init>(SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler.java:43)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.AbstractAuthenticationFilterConfigurer.failureUrl(AbstractAuthenticationFilterConfigurer.java:199)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.AbstractAuthenticationFilterConfigurer.updateAuthenticationDefaults(AbstractAuthenticationFilterConfigurer.java:345)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.AbstractAuthenticationFilterConfigurer.loginPage(AbstractAuthenticationFilterConfigurer.java:285)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.FormLoginConfigurer.loginPage(FormLoginConfigurer.java:181)
    at org.webapp.security.SecurityConfig.configure(SecurityConfig.java:27)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.getHttp(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.init(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:276)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.init(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:61)
    at org.webapp.security.SecurityConfig$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$f93abbff.init(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.init(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:369)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.doBuild(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:322)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:39)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.springSecurityFilterChain(WebSecurityConfiguration.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$93d7a5f4.CGLIB$springSecurityFilterChain$0(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$93d7a5f4$$FastClassByCGLIB$$eb934d27.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:286)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$93d7a5f4.springSecurityFilterChain(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:160)
    ... 24 more

Mar 29, 2014 4:18:30 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
Grave: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public javax.servlet.Filter org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.springSecurityFilterChain() throws java.lang.Exception] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'spring/index?error' is not a valid redirect URL
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:581)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1025)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:921)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:487)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:628)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4937)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public javax.servlet.Filter org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.springSecurityFilterChain() throws java.lang.Exception] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'spring/index?error' is not a valid redirect URL
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:181)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:570)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'spring/index?error' is not a valid redirect URL
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(Assert.java:65)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler.setDefaultFailureUrl(SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler.java:98)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler.<init>(SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler.java:43)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.AbstractAuthenticationFilterConfigurer.failureUrl(AbstractAuthenticationFilterConfigurer.java:199)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.AbstractAuthenticationFilterConfigurer.updateAuthenticationDefaults(AbstractAuthenticationFilterConfigurer.java:345)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.AbstractAuthenticationFilterConfigurer.loginPage(AbstractAuthenticationFilterConfigurer.java:285)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.FormLoginConfigurer.loginPage(FormLoginConfigurer.java:181)
    at org.webapp.security.SecurityConfig.configure(SecurityConfig.java:27)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.getHttp(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.init(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:276)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.init(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:61)
    at org.webapp.security.SecurityConfig$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$f93abbff.init(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.init(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:369)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.doBuild(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:322)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:39)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.springSecurityFilterChain(WebSecurityConfiguration.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$93d7a5f4.CGLIB$springSecurityFilterChain$0(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$93d7a5f4$$FastClassByCGLIB$$eb934d27.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:286)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$93d7a5f4.springSecurityFilterChain(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:160)
    ... 24 more
```

Comment: Where does your form submit to?

Comment: what you mean? I have an view (index.jsp) where it's placed the form, which is mapped in the controller. If I run the application, I get an error 404, unless I directly access to localhost:8080/spring/index (typinf the address in the address bar of browser). This happens with our without the Spring Security configuration, but with the Spring Security configured at least i get an default login page before the error page.

Comment: Ah sorry, I mistunderstood. Maybe a good place to start is having your  mappings and urls prefixed with `/`.

Comment: yes, I have tried that, but still don't work. I just look in the eclipse console, and the error I add to topic is displayed.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot initialize context because there is already a root application context present - check whether you have multiple ContextLoader* definitions in your web.xml!
```

In your `WebAppInitializer`, you are registering a `ContextLoaderListener`.

Because you are using `AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer` with the `super` [constructor that accepts a `Class[]`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/context/AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer.html#AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer%28java.lang.Class...%29)

> Creates a new instance that will instantiate the ContextLoaderListener with the specified classes.

that also registers a `ContextLoaderListener`. Note the class javadoc

> When used with `AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer(Class...)`, it
>   will also register a `ContextLoaderListener`. When used with
>   `AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer()`, this class is typically
>   used in addition to a subclass of `AbstractContextLoaderInitializer`.

As the error states, you cannot have two `ContextLoaderListener` instances because they will both try to create and add a `ApplicationContext` to the `ServletContext`.

Comment: ok, then i try two things (not simultaneously). I remove the register of ContextLoaderListener from WebInitializer and the call to super from SecurityWebApplicationInitializer.  in both cases I get the error **Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'spring/index?error' is not a valid redirect URL** in the console of eclipse, but I dont't declare this url in any place.

Comment: @KleberMota Please add the full stack trace in your question.

Comment: Ok, I just add to the topic the stacktrack after the changes in the code. Just for the record, what I did was or comment the line **super(SecurityConfig)** from the SecurityWebApplicationInitializer, or comment the line **container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext))** from WebAppInitializer

Comment: @KleberMota I don't know Spring Security well enough to be sure, but it seems that the `loginPage` and the other methods expect actual URLS rather than relative paths/view names.

Comment: do you mean things like this: **/WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp** instead **/spring/index**?

Comment: @KleberMota No, a URL being the address that a client uses to reach your server. I think you're just missing the preceding `/` .

Comment: Yes, I did this - put the preceding slash. Now I don't get any error in the console (stack trace), but still get an 404 error in the browser.

Comment: @KleberMota Should I take it that it works now? For 404, turn on your debug logs and check which paths Spring registers for handling requests.

Comment: Yep, now it's finally working. In fact, after I had correct both Initializers,I still have an error on my viewResolver, wich I correct too. Anyway, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that this:

```
.loginPage("spring/index").permitAll()
```

should be this:

```
.loginPage("/spring/index").permitAll() //note the '/' at the beginning of the uri
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there're some conflicting overlapping between your `web.xml` and java-based `configuration class`. That's the root cause when I met the same error as you. And my solution is to comment out the duplicated configuration in `web.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

I had a class

> MyContextLoaderListener extends ContextLoaderListener

somewhere in my code. It was unused. Spring boot apparently used reflection to find it. I deleted the file and the problem was gone