# No WebApplicationContext found: no ContextLoaderListener registered?, but not every time that start the server

Tags: java, spring

I really need your help to solve this problem... I'm working with Spring-MVC 4.1.6.RELEASE, Spring-Security 4.0.0.RELEASE

I'm having this ERROR just... "sometimes" when I start the server. That's the real problem it just happens sometimes.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No WebApplicationContext found: no ContextLoaderListener registered?
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:252)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Then you will say, that's easy you just have to add a ContextLoaderListener but when I do, I get this:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot initialize context because there is already a root application context present - check whether you have multiple ContextLoader* definitions in your web.xml!
```

But it is not always... So I guess there is something wrong in the order that the context are being initialized but I don't know how to fix it...

These are my configuration classes:

WebInitializer.java

```
public class WebInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext)
        throws ServletException {

    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    rootContext.register(ServerApplicationConfig.class);
    servletContext.addListener(new RequestContextListener());
    servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));

    FacesServlet facesServlet = new FacesServlet();
    ServletRegistration.Dynamic facesServletDynamic = servletContext.addServlet("facesServlet", facesServlet);
    facesServletDynamic.addMapping("*.jsf");
    facesServletDynamic.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    servletContext.addListener(ConfigureListener.class);

    //Oauth2Filter
    servletContext.addFilter("auth2ClientContextFilter", OAuth2ClientContextFilter.class);

    }
}
```

ServerApplicationConfig.java

```
    @EnableWebMvc
@Import({ WebSecurityConfig.class, HibernateConfig.class })
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.agrichem.server" }, scopedProxy = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
@Configuration
public class ServerApplicationConfig {

    @Bean
    public PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer getPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/UTC"));

        PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer ppc = new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();

        ClassPathResource[] resources = new ClassPathResource[] {
                new ClassPathResource("jdbc.properties"),
                new ClassPathResource("oada-client.properties") };

        ppc.setLocations(resources);

        return ppc;
    }

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("viewResolver")
    public ViewResolver getViewResolver() {
        UrlBasedViewResolver viewResolver = new UrlBasedViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JsfView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/views/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".xhtml");

        return viewResolver;
    }
}
```

WebSecurityInitializer.java

```
@Configuration
@Order(1)
public class WebSecurityInitializer extends
        AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {

}
```

WebSecurityConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("customUserDetailsService")
    private UserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
            throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();

        http.logout().logoutUrl("/logout.jsf").permitAll()
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/home/login.jsf");

        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("*.css", "*.js", "**.gif", "*.jpg", "*.jpeg",
                        "*.png", "*.css.jsf", "*.js.jsf", "**.gif.jsf",
                        "*.jpg.jsf", "*.jpeg.jsf", "*.png.jsf")
                .permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/**/*.css", "/**/*.js", "/**/*.gif", "/**/*.jpg",
                        "/**/*.jpeg", "/**/*.png", "/**/*.css.jsf",
                        "/**/*.js.jsf", "/**/*.gif.jsf", "/**/*.jpg.jsf",
                        "/**/*.jpeg.jsf", "/**/*.png.jsf")
                .permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/**/*.woff2", "/**/*.eot", "/**/*.woff",
                        "/**/*.ttf", "/**/*.svg", "*.woff2", "*.eot", "*.woff",
                        "*.ttf", "*.svg", "/**/*.woff2.jsf", "/**/*.eot.jsf", "/**/*.woff.jsf",
                        "/**/*.ttf.jsf", "/**/*.svg.jsf", "*.woff2.jsf", "*.eot.jsf", "*.woff.jsf",
                        "*.ttf.jsf", "*.svg.jsf")
                .permitAll();

        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/admin/**.jsf").hasRole("ADMIN");

        // http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/farms/**.jsf").hasAnyRole("HEAD_OFFICER");

        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/home/logout.jsf").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/rest/**").permitAll();

        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and().formLogin()
                .loginPage("/home/login.jsf").permitAll()
                .failureUrl("/home/login.jsf?error=denied").permitAll()
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/home/index.jsf", true);
    }

}
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22729725/why-this-spring-application-with-java-based-configuration-dont-work-properly

Comment: Hey @PawełGłowacz thanks for your response.. Yes I checked that before and I understand the problem that's why I don't get why when I remove this line `servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));` it doesn't work.... sometimes..