# Tried to add spring security to existing project and now get cannot initialize context error

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Trying to add security to the Spring Pet Clinic application. I do this by adding two classes: `MessageSecurityWebApplicationInitizializer` and `SecurityConfig` to this project and now I get this error:

```
Cannot initialize context because there is already a root application context present - check whether you have multiple ContextLoader* definitions in your web.xml!
```

Indeed in `web.xml` there is mention of the `ContextLoaderListener`.

`MessageSecurityWebApplicationInitizializer` just extends `AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer` with no customization. I believe this class is what loads the additional `ContextLoaderListener` but not sure how to prevent this or if doing so is desirable. I tried implementing the interface and doing what is suggested in this question: 
[Why this Spring application with java-based configuration don't work properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22729725/why-this-spring-application-with-java-based-configuration-dont-work-properly)

But this did not work.

I am wondering if I am trying to mix Spring XML configuration with non-XML configuration or something. But mainly I would like to get the security to work.

Comment: You are right. Remove or rename web.xml and it should get rid of this error message.

Comment: But I believe the application relies on web.xml for other things.