# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot initialize context because there is already a root application context present

Tags: spring, illegalstateexception, applicationcontext

When running my webapp, I get the stacktrace listed below every other try. Note that there doesn't seem to be multiple ContextLoader definitions im web.xml as far as I can tell. Moreover, the app runs just fine the second/fourth/etc. time. This behaviour is much harder to debug than if it simply didn't work. Can anyone shed some light on this?

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot initialize context because there is already a root application context present - check whether you have multiple ContextLoader* definitions in your web.xml!
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:299)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4795)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5221)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:724)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:700)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:714)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:919)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1703)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: It would be helpful to provide your deployment descriptor (web.xml). Also take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22729725/why-this-spring-application-with-java-based-configuration-dont-work-properly

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I figured out the problem and posted the answer below.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For anyone with a similar problem - turns out that spring-jersey used in the project was setting up its own context. My context and the spring-jersey one were initialized in random order apparently.
More info here: 
https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-2038 
https://java.net/projects/jersey/lists/users/archive/2014-03/message/124 
The suggested solution of adding:

```
servletContext.setInitParameter("contextConfigLocation", "<NONE>");
```

In WebAppInitializer implementation didn't work reliably due to initialization order. What solved the problem was adding its xml equivalent:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value></param-value>
</context-param>
```

as the firt parameter in web.xml, ensuring that its set before the context is initialized.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this solve my problem. I am using Spring, Spring Security, Jersey and Hibernate in my JSF project. After having to add jersey-spring4 and spring-bridge to solve my null entity manager problem, I was having multiple context loader issue, and this solution works!

Answer (score 7):

Make sure that you are not doing this if you are using spring boot

```
  container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));
```