# EntityManager is null in Jersey controller in Spring project with JPA (EclipseLink)

Tags: spring, jpa, jersey, eclipselink, entitymanager

I am trying to develop a simple Spring web application using Jersey (JAX-RS), deployed in a Tomcat container. The entities are managed using JPA with EclipseLink provider and stored in a MySQL database. I don't use EJB.

I'm trying to inject the EntityManager via Spring, however when I want to get (or persist) an entity from the DB, I get a NullPointerException showing that EntityManager is null.

I have spent lots of hours trying to find the solution and tried every code I've found in tutorials and threads, but got the same result.

I have included all the required dependecies in the project. If I manually create an EntityManagerFactory and then an EntityManager in getPerson, it works, but I don't think that should be the proper way.
Also, when I start the service, I can see in the console output logs that Spring root WebApplicationContext is initialized, bean definitions are loaded and JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'defaultPU' is built.

I am clearly missing something, could you please help me how can I make this work? 
Why is EntityManager null and how should I inject it in order to be able to use it in the PersonController?

Person.java:

```
package TestSpringApp;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Person {
    @Id
    private int id;
    private String name;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

PersonController.java:

```
package TestSpringApp;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;

@Component
@Path("/person")
public class PersonController {

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager entityManager;

    @GET
    @Transactional
    public String getPerson() {
        Person p = entityManager.find(Person.class, 0);
        return p.getName();
    }

    public void setEntityManager(EntityManager em) {
        this.entityManager = em;
    }

    public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return this.entityManager;
    }
}
```

beans.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation=
        "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="TestSpringApp"/>

    <tx:annotation-driven />

    <context:annotation-config/>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaAdapter" />
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="defaultPU"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="jpaAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter">
        <property name="database" value="MYSQL" />
        <property name="showSql" value="true" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

persistence.xml:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd"
             version="1.0">
    <persistence-unit name="defaultPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>TestSpringApp.Person</class>

        <properties>
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="root"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables" />
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode" value="database" />
            <property name="eclipselink.weaving" value="false"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

web.xml:

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
         http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:beans.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <display-name>testspring</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>/</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>TestSpringApp</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>/</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

EDIT:

Until now, I have thought that context:component-scan or context:annotation-config in beans.xml was taking care of making Spring aware of PersonController, however now I checked it and I found out that setEntityManager is only called if I place @PersistenceContext on setEntityManager instead of on EntityManager itself and annotate the PersonController class with @Component. This way I can see that setEntityManager is called on Spring bean initialization, and its value is "Shared EntityManager proxy for target factory [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean@15bd577]".
My problem still occurs, because when I do a http://localhost:8080/rest/person request, entityManager is still null in line entityManager.find(Person.class, 0).

Comment: I only know what I've seen in tutorials, but how is Spring made aware of your PersonController class - how is it being loaded when you see the NPE?

Comment: Please see my edit in the original post regarding your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading through Jersey docs, I have found [this chapter](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/spring.html) on Spring DI support in Jersey.

Adding `jersey-spring3` and `spring-bridge` dependecies to the project solved the problem.

Comment: Can you give more information about `spring-bridge` dependency? Did you mean this one? https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.hk2/spring-bridge

Comment: I am using spring security Java config as well. After adding jersey-spring4 and spring-bridge (big thank you!), I have mulltiple context loader problem in my project. I have to add a context-param to solve it per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33633098/java-lang-illegalstateexception-cannot-initialize-context-because-there-is-alre