# Adding SecurityWebApplicationInitializer to existing Spring app

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-java-config

I try to follow answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22729725/why-this-spring-application-with-java-based-configuration-dont-work-properly), but still cannot make it work.
I have following Java config classes:

```
public class MyWebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
          rootContext.register(WebAppConfiguration.class);
          container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));
          AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext dispatcherContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();  
          ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = container.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(dispatcherContext));
          dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
          dispatcher.addMapping("/");
    }
}
```

And for security:

```
public class SecurityWebApplicationInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {
    public SecurityWebApplicationInitializer() {
        super(WebSecurityConfiguration.class);
    }
}
```

The problem is I get exception like that on startup:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot initialize context because there is already a root application context present - check whether you have multiple ContextLoader* definitions in your web.xml!
```

Without `SecurityWebApplicationInitializer` class it starts up and works fine except of the fact that Spring Security doesn't work.
I understand that the problem is that `SecurityWebApplicationInitializer` injects it's own context. But then what is the right way to make the Spring Security work for my case?
Thank you.

Comment: did u try removing ` container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));` from `MyWebAppInitializer ` class?

Comment: Most logical solution ended up the easiest and correct... Now it works, thank you.