# Spring Session security config and multiple contextLoaderListener classes exception

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-session

I am trying to integrate Spring Session 1.2.0 to an existing Spring MVC project with already configured Spring Security.

I have done configuration according to these:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/1.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html5/guides/security.html

http://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/1.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html5/guides/httpsession-jdbc.html

However, I cannot deploy the app on tomcat since I keep getting exception:

`SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot initialize context because there is already a root application context present - check whether you have multiple ContextLoader* definitions in your web.xml!
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:277)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4992)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5492)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:649)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1083)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1879)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)`

There is related issue [Why this Spring application with java-based configuration don't work properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22729725/why-this-spring-application-with-java-based-configuration-dont-work-properly)

How do I configure Spring Session without creating a new instance of `ContextLoaderListener`?

Comment: In the existing application, how do you load the Spring Security configuration?

Comment: I had actually an existing Spring Security configuration and having two of those created the problem mentioned. So, this was my own fault because of not understanding this in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I had already a Spring Security configuration. To solve my problem I put the annotation `@EnableJdbcHttpSession` in the existing configuration and made sure that data source and transanction manager are configured.

Comment: Did your problem got solved? I am also running into same issue